# Getting server error message while parsing json using NSURLConnection in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, xcode, nsurlconnection

```
[
{
    "CouponQtn":1,
    "DeliveryDist":14,
    "Sizes":"not selected",
    "CustomerAlternateMobile":"01700790900",
    "deliveryCharge":0,
    "DealId":744706,
    "PaymentType":"MPD",
    "OrderFrom":"ios",
    "CardType":"Manual",
    "OrderSource":"app",
    "CustomerId":630142,
    "MerchantId":15196,
    "AdvPaymentType":0,
    "CustomerBillingAddress":"Khulna",
    "CustomerMobile":"01700790900",
    "Color":"",
    "AdvPayPhoneId":0,
    "OrderCouponPrice":375

}
]
```

This is my json format populated from the app and I am sending it to server in a post method to get a desired json result. But the server is providing me an unknown error. But it is working in Postman as well 
 Here I convert my array of dictionary to json

```
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:orderArray
                                                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                                                     error:nil];
                                NSString*jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                               //NSString* jsonStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[jsonData bytes]];


                                tempDic = [apiCom getNodeDataByPOST:CART_ORDER_URL parameter:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonStr]];
```

Here orderArray is my array of dictionary and my parsing code is provided below

```
 -(NSDictionary*)getNodeDataByPOST:(NSString*)url parameter:(id)parameter{

    NSDictionary *dictionaryData;
    NSDictionary *dic;
    Reachability *reachTest = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachTest  currentReachabilityStatus];
    if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN)){
        dictionaryData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"error",@"status",@"No Network",@"message",nil];
        dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dictionaryData, @"response",nil];
        return dic;
    }

    else{
        NSURL *adUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:url];

        NSMutableURLRequest *requestURL = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:adUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:900.00];
        //NSLog(@"%@",requestURL);
        [requestURL setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


        NSError *error=nil ;
        if ([parameter isKindOfClass : [NSString class]]) {
           [requestURL setHTTPBody:[parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        }
//        else if([parameter isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
//            [requestURL setHTTPBody:parameter];
//        }
        else if([parameter isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]||[parameter isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [requestURL setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameter options:0 error:nil]];

        }
        else {
            [requestURL setHTTPBody:parameter];
        }
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error1=nil;
        //        NSLog(@"%@\n\n%@",s,parameter);
        NSData *apiData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestURL returningResponse:&response error:&error1];

        if (!apiData) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }

        if (response.statusCode == 0) {

            dictionaryData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"error",@"status",@"Server Error",@"message",nil];
            return dic;

        }
        else if(response.statusCode == 404) {
            dictionaryData= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"error",@"status",@"Server is Currently Down.",@"message", nil];
            return dic;

        }
        else {
            dictionaryData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:apiData options:kNilOptions error:&error];


        }
    }
    return dictionaryData;
}
```

I didn't find any coding or logical error from my side. I have used this code several times and it worked fine. Is there any settings are permission required in the app side?

Thanks ....

Comment: Apart from the issue don't use a synchronous URL request. `sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated for a long time.

Comment: And what's the error you have?

Comment: I am getting the error 
Message = "An error has occurred.";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that its working fine in Postman, you should check if the request in to send in form-url encoded formate. If it is, you should add the following line

```
       [requestURL setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: I have added the line but no luck at all

Comment: can you tell that which type of encoding you are using?
And where you add this line of code?

Comment: NSMutableURLRequest *requestURL = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:adUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:900.00];

        NSLog(@"%@",requestURL);

         [requestURL setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [requestURL setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];        
        NSError *error=nil ;

        if ([parameter isKindOfClass : [NSString class]]) {
           [requestURL setHTTPBody:[parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }

Comment: can you check that which if() condition working, and take the parameter and check it in Postman.

Comment: Chances are, if a page expects JSON, it wants the content type to be JSON, not URL-encoded fields.  I mean, I guess a page could expect JSON in a single field, but that would be kind of weird.

Answer (score 0):

I use this line and works like a magic for me

```
 [requestURL setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```